Uniformly distributed random vector is point symmetric.
A random vector $X$ is called point symmetric around $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ if $X - a \overset{D}{=} a - X$.
Let $U = (U_1, \dots, U_d)$, where $U_i \sim U(0, 1)$ is a uniformly distributed random vector with a multivariate distribution function $C$.
How can I prove that $U$ is point symmetric only about $a = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \dots, \frac{1}{2}\right)$?
While the case $d = 1$ is straightforward, the proof for $d > 1$ is less clear. What approach should be taken to demonstrate this result in higher dimensions?

Are the $U_i$ independent?
